# @Transactional(readOnly=true) vs @QueryHints

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, spring-data, repository

I've got a Spring Data JPA Repository with a method like this:

```
//@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.readOnly", value = "true") })
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
Account findByUsername(String username);
```

When `Account` is dirty, hibernate tries to flush it when invoking this method - which I don't want. I thought setting it to `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` could help with this, but it doesn't. Interestingly using `@QueryHints` with the concrete hibernate hint *does* work. Now I'm wondering why. Shouldn't `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` have the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to stick to non-vendor specific ways you then i would try:

**Option 1**

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
Account findByUsername(String username);
```

Here we do run the query outside of any transaction, thus not affecting the existing state of persistence context. Think well if this case is suitable for this configuration.

**Option 2**

I assume you are doing some other modifications in the current transaction before you query for the user. I would suggest then setting the flush mode to commit on you query (or entity manager):

```
EntityManager em;
Account findByUsername(String username){
   em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

  // perform the query
}
```

OR

```
EntityManager em;
Account findByUsername(String username){
  Query query = em.createQuery(..); 
  query.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

  // perform the query
}
```

The COMMIT flush mode tells the persistence provider that queries do not overlap with changed data in the persistence context, so it does not need to do anything in order to get the correct results.

Setting the flush mode on the query itself is an advisable approach.

**Update: Option 3**

As the last resort you can set that on the core configuration itself:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>
```

Now this is to use when you cannot access the entity manager and set the flush mode manually.

Comment: Option 2b sounds interesting, but I'm using Spring Data Repositories where Spring Data is generating the queries automatically based on the interface method names. So I don't get the actual query into my hands. Hence I thought I could add that hint via annotation instead and Spring picks it up for me and sets it on the query it generates. Of course, I could build my own Repository Impl and do the stuff there, but I'm lazy :).

Comment: I see your point but with easy of automatic configuration comes the pain of custom cases that need to be handled. Tool cannot think about everything you would want to do. Imagine that .. no one would need developers anymore..

Comment: one more option came to my head

Comment: Yeah, that would change it for all transactions. I just want to have it on a special case basis. Meanwhile I simply avoid the flushing by not changing the object before the call. So I'm going accept you answer which provides some good options!

Comment: Great! Glad it gave you some value.